# dpkg error while installing fail2ban on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, 15.04, dpkg

I'm trying to reinstall fail2ban after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04. I was getting these errors so I did apt-get remove fail2ban and then apt-get install fail2ban, however I still get these error messages when installing other packages.

Output of "sudo apt-get install -f"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up fail2ban (0.9.1-1) ...
Job for fail2ban.service failed. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript fail2ban, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package fail2ban (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fail2ban
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Output of "systemctl status fail2ban.service"

```
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2015-07-26 22:03:08 EDT; 4min 48s ago
 Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 3036 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=255)

Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: Unit fail2ban.service entered failed state.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service failed.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for fail2ban.service
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: Unit fail2ban.service entered failed state.
Jul 26 22:03:08 pimr15 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service failed.
```

Also, I should point out it seems fail2ban is indeed working as "sudo fail2ban-client status" returns my jails

Answer (score 1):

I added the dependency "python3-systemd" and continued getting the error, however on restarting, the dpkg code fixed and it's good to go. Way to go me! :D